# How to build an adb the same size as the one from android sdk

Tags: android, adb

I want to build an adb tool from android official source code. And I can simply finish the job via typing the following cmds:

```
apt-get install mingw32
make USE_MINGW=y adb
```

My problem is the adb tool builded from source code has a size of about 4.4MB , while the adb in android sdk/platform-tools has only a size of 796KB.

How does that difference come from? Can anyone give any ideas? I want to know how to edit the make file or souce code to reduce the output file's size.

======

After google for a while, it is said just remove the debug info to reduce the size, so it seems I get close to the final solutin :)

Comment: Try compiling with different `-O` options and then `strip` the result.

Comment: @Aleks G I do not quitely understand what you said :(

Comment: look at the compiler flags in the make file - are there any `O` flags?  `-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3`, etc.? Also make sure that `-g` or `-gg` flags are NOT included. Finally, after it's compiled, do `strip adb`.  This will strip all debug symbol information from the executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Longerian's answer, there are other tricks that can result in modest size reductions. See [Android NDK: How to Reduce Binaries Size](http://blog.algolia.com/android-ndk-how-to-reduce-libs-size/) for details. You might have to change some build flags and options.

Comment: Note that this is not an ndk binary but rather a host tool, though many of the same techniques would apply.